# Is there a way to make a data frame out of an RD object?

Tags: r, regression, tidyverse

I am running an RD regression and would like to tidy it up to export its output into an excel. However, when I try to use the `tidy()` function:

```
R2to1RDD = rdd::RDestimate(data = filter(group_by(Affinity_County_Weekly.csv, countyfips, WeekAfterReopening2to1 < 5 & WeekAfterReopening2to1 > -5), Reopening2to1), 
                      changeVsLastWeekSpend ~ WeekAfterReopening2to1,
              #  |  factor(winner1001010) + factor(income_quartile),
                cutpoint = 0
                #type = "sharp" 
)
summary(R2to1RDD)
R2to1RDDDF = tidy(R2to1RDD)
```

Returns an error:

> "Error: No tidy method for objects of class RD" is returned.

Here is the data:

```
 countyfips WeekAfterStimulusPayments changeVsLastWeekSpend
   <fct>                          <dbl> <pseries>            
 1 1001                              -4 -15.0165017          
 2 1001                              -3 -34.1747573          
 3 1001                              -2  11.3569322          
 4 1001                              -1   3.3112583          
 5 1001                               0   1.0256410          
 6 1001                               1  17.6015228          
 7 1001                               2  -1.8236754          
 8 1001                               3  -0.6375027          
 9 1001                               4  16.9800885          
10 1003                              -4  -7.7897083
```

Is there any other way to make a data frame out of an regression object, specifically an RD object?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. As the data are missing, it is rather tricky to reason about the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added the data

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x object 'WeekAfterReopening2to1' not found
ℹ Input `..2` is `WeekAfterReopening2to1 < 5 & WeekAfterReopening2to1 > -5`.

Comment: It is unclear how exactly is your code supposed to run with the data. Would it be possible, to make minimal self-contained piece of code that illustrates your problem? (e.g. a piece of code that is possible to source and contains all the necessary data). Alternatively, have the file in a format, that can be reasonably loaded.